# USB Ports not working - Unknown usb device(port reset failed)

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, window, sony-vaio

Today, I opened my laptop to transfer some files from a USB device. But my Sony Vaio laptop did not detect the usb from any ports (I have 2 ports). I tried it on another pc and the USB worked fine.

I opened the device manager and found this:
[image: device manager]

I tried uninstalling and restarting but it did not work.

Laptop specs:
[image: specs]

Edit:
Laptop model : SONY VAIO PCG-81114L
after following second point of harrymc the following drivers are there:
[drivers after unisntalling unknown usb device and restarting(same result as b4 following the step)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwJDg.png)

**EDIT 2 :**

[image]

Comment: 90% of USB issues are caused by incorrect / faulty USB cable. Replace USB cable and try again...

Comment: Why do you think there's a cable involved? It's a laptop and presumably a USB flash drive, commonly called "USB".

Answer (score 1):

General USB troubleshooting:

- **Verify hardware**
  Connect the device to your PC using another USB cable, a different USB port,
  or connect the device to another PC. Try also other USB devices.
  This will tell if the problem is hardware.
  (This part was already done.)
- **Uninstall the USB Drivers**
  Open Device Manager and expand category *Universal Serial Bus Controllers*,
  right-click on all "Unknown USB Device (Port Reset Failed)" and then click
  *Uninstall* to remove the device.
  Finally, restart the PC so Windows will reinstall the device automatically.
- **Update the Generic USB Hub Drivers**

  - Open Device Manager and expand *Universal Serial Bus controllers*
  - Right-click on all Generic USB Hub devices and select "Update Driver Software…"
  - Select "Browse my computer for driver software"
  - Select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"
  - Check the box next to "Show compatible hardware" and select Generic USB Hub.
  - Click on the Next button
  - If successful, the message will be "Windows has successfully updated your drivers"
  - Reboot.

For more details with screenshots see the article
[How to Fix Unknown USB Device (Port Reset Failed) Issue for Windows 10](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-unknown-usb-device-port-reset-failed-issue/).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104562/discussion-on-answer-by-harrymc-usb-ports-not-working-unknown-usb-deviceport).